# Using std::string as return type in Boost.python exported function

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have a very simple example of a C++ function that I export to python (2.7.13) via Boost.Python. Code below:

```
#include <string>

#include <boost/python.hpp>

const char* greet()
{
    return "hello, world!";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libhello)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("hello_world", greet);
}
```

I compile on a OSX 10.10.5 machine with

```
g++ -I ~/boost -L ~/boost/stage/lib\
-L /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current\
-fpic export.cpp -shared -lboost_python -lPython -olibhello.so
```

It correctly produces the `libhello.so` which I can then use in python

```
import libhello as lh
lh.hello_world() # correctly returns the string "hello, world"
```

However, when I change the return type of `greet` in the C++ file to `std::string`, i.e.

```
std::string greet(){...}
```

I am getting the following crash in python after running `lh.hello_world()`:

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate
Abort trap: 6
```

and python crashes. Any idea why? Does it have to do with the non-POD return type?

Comment: I can confirm `std::string greet(){...}` is working fine for me on `Ubuntu 17.4 / g++-6.3.0 / boost 1.62` so this must be something to do with what you have on your UNIX-like machine installed.

Comment: @doqtor Ok, thanks! I'll see what's going on on my side then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be related to the `libpython` the linker used by default, which was the OSX original one located within `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. When I linked agains `libpython` from my installation of `python` located within `Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`, everything worked fine. The whole command line I used is posted below, in case someone bumps into this in the future:

```
g++ -I /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/\
 -I $HOME/boost -fpic export.cpp -shared -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -olibhello.so\
 -L /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib\
 -L $HOME/boost/stage/lib
```